# When adding a record to oracle 11g, it says successful but there is no record added, returns a blank details page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am new to ASP.Net MVC C#. I am trying to add a new record to Oracle 11g database using ASP.Net MVC C# and stored procedures. But it is not adding, when I fill out the form and hit submit, it says Added Successfully, but when I check the database, the record is not there.

I have browsed multiple sites and used the patterns in the examples they provided, still, there is no solution. The code and the Data Access Layer all seem to be working and the application is not giving any errors.

Data Access Layer:

```
public string Insert(Participant participant)
{
    string newParticipant = "";

    try
    {
        oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("InsertProcedures.register", oracleConnection);
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20)).Value = participant.FirstName;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("vmiddlename", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 12)).Value = participant.MiddleName;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("lname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 35)).Value = participant.LastName;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pname", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20)).Value = participant.PreferredName;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("dob", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = participant.DateOfBirth;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("gender", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4)).Value = participant.Gender;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("createdby", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 25)).Value = participant.CreatedBy;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("resultCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        oracleConnection.Open();
        oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        return newParticipant = "";
    }
    oracleConnection.Close();
    return newParticipant;
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddNewParticipant()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewParticipant(Participant participant)
{
    participant.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(participant.DateOfBirth);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string result = DAL.Insert(participant);

        ViewBag.Message = "Participant Added Successfully";
        TempData["addResult"] = result;
        ModelState.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("ShowAllDetails");
    }            
    else
    {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error in saving data");
         return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/DatePicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Add New</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <form asp-action="AddParticipant" method="post" role="form">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class="control-label"})
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = "First Name" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreferredName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreferredName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PreferredName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker", @placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 addLabel">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 addInput">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
                            {
                                new SelectListItem{Text = "Male", Value = "M"},
                                new SelectListItem{Text = "Female", Value = "F"},
                                new SelectListItem{Text = "Transgender", Value = "T"},
                            }, "Choose Gender", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="addButtons form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-dark" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-dark" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
        </div>
    }
    <div style="color:blue; font-family:Arial">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Records", "ShowAllDetails")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know tools you use, but - as of Oracle, you need to *commit* the action if you want to permanently store data into the database. Submit you mentioned might be doing that, but - if it does not - see if you can execute `commit` after `insert`; maybe it'll help.

Comment: I am trying out what you suggested, how do I execute commit after insert, is there a way or adding it to the data access layer?

Comment: As I said, I don't know tools you use. Sorry.